# After updating props, this.props is always === nextProps / prevProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a jsbin for this issue here: http://jsbin.com/tekuluve/1/edit

In an onClick event I'm removing an element from the model, and re-rendering the app. But strangely, in componentWillReceiveProps() (and componentWillUpdate, and componentDidUpdate too), nextProps is always === to this.props, regardless of what I do.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var Box = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="box" onClick={ UpdateModel }>
        { this.props.label }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Grid = React.createClass({
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {      
    // WTF is going on here???
    console.log(nextProps.boxes === this.props.boxes)        
  },
  render: function() {
    var boxes = _.map(this.props.boxes, function(d) {
      return (<Box label={ d.number } />);
    });

    return (
      <div className="grid">
        { boxes }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var model = [
  { number: 1 },
  { number: 2 },
  { number: 3 },
  { number: 4 },
  { number: 5 }
];

function UpdateModel() {
  React.renderComponent(
    <Grid boxes={ _.pull(model, _.sample(model)) } />,
    document.body
  );
}

React.renderComponent(
  <Grid boxes={ model } />,
  document.body
);
```

I need nextProps to be different to this.props after it has been updated via UpdateModel(), in the componentWillReceiveProps() lifecycle event.

Comment: why aren't you using states?

Comment: Because that doesn't fit the use-case I'm building towards. I'm attempting to build some lifecycle methods which allow me to pass in dynamic props to unmounting components, so first I need to determine which components are unmounting, hence the comparison in componentWillReceiveProps().

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. when componentWillReceiveProps is called, when I try to access this.props, it's already the same as nextProps. I can't access the old props to compare them. My props have definitely changed, and I don't have access to what the props were before the component received props.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`===` will check if it's the same object. It seems that what you're doing is mutating the value that the `boxes` property points to.

Comment: Marking this as the answer because it's somewhat close-ish. I resolved this issue by adding model = model.slice(); to the first line of the UpdateModel() method.

Comment: If you want to mutate the model without calling setState, you can always invoke forceRender() on the component instance returned by `React.renderComponent` :)

Answer (score 15):

Something like this occurred for me using Flux Stores to store my state in the manner suggested by the official Todo List tutorial (http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html). For anyone else finding this after following the tutorial, a problem seems to arise in the TodoStore in the getAll() method, because it returns a direct reference to the internal data object:

```
getAll: function() {
  return _todos;
}
```

This seems to breaks the ability of the lifecycle methods like componentDidUpdate(prevProps) to distinguish between the old and new props. I think the reason is that by passing a direct reference to the Store's data object into the views, the state/props effectively change immediately when the Store changes rather than after new values are passed down through the lifecycle methods, so old and new props always contain the same values. This could be solved by passing a copy of the internal data object _todos rather than the object itself,

for example, when _todos is an object,

```
getAll: function() {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_todos));
}
```

If _todos is an array, return _todos.slice() can be used instead.

In general, if using a Store to contain state information and call it from your controller-views, it seems advisable to return a copy of the data rather than a reference to the original, since the original will be mutated when state changes occur.

Comment: Do we need to create new object for each and every state change?

Comment: If you want to avoid copying the whole state each time, I think you could use more specific change events and getter functions to just get the part that changed and update the existing state of your controller-view with the difference.

Comment: Note that this and various `cloneDeep` approaches (like with lodash/underscore) won't work on certain native objects like `File`s that you get from `<input type='file'>` as you lose native methods used in the upload process (and not every property is serializable)

Comment: This solved it for me. I has implemented Flux and was indeed passing down   as props a direct reference to an object in the store. I ended up using lodash' `_.assign({}, object)` to copy the object.

Comment: We used a similar approach in a large scale application and it resulted in significant performance problems. Our initial approach varied in an important aspect -- we were simulating PureRenderMixin with a string comparison to support deep checks. In SCU we would check if `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props) === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nextProps)`. This was a bad approach. The operation is too heavy for such a frequently called method. Now we just make sure to return a new obj on changes in the store, something like `this.state.someData = _.extend({}, newData)`

Answer (score 11):

You could use Immutable.js. It is a library that Facebook made to work with react/flux.
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

We have been stumped by this a couple of times.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) { 
    return this.props.myObj !== nextProps.myObj
}
```

Many times, some value inside the myObj object would change. However the above function would return false. The reason being that both `this.props.myObj` and `nextProps.myObj` were referencing/pointing to the same object.

By implementing Immutable.js, the data will always be passed down as clones (instead of referencing the same object, they will actually be separate objects).

It re-enforces flux's uni-directional flow. You will never be able to (accidentally) modify the original data that is being passed into your component (whether as props or from a flux store).

This also enables you to use a PureRenderMixin – which automatically stops the render if the values of state/props have not changed. This could help with performance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed it. **The problem was changing the prop without deep cloning it.**

my prop was an `array of objects` and i was changing it on parent with :

```
let newtodos = [...this.state.todos];
newtodos[0].text = 'changed text';
this.setState({ todos : newtodos });
```

So in `componentDidUpdate` i was getting the wrong result:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  //prevProps.todos is always equal to this.props.todos, since you changed the prop object directly.
  if(JSON.stringify(prevProps.todos) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.todos){...}
}
```

So i fixed it with:

```
// let newtodos = [...this.state.todos]; // SHALLOW COPY - Wrong
let newtodos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.todos)); // Deep Clone - Right
newtodos[0].text = 'changed text';
this.setState({ todos : newtodos });
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to implementing Immutable.js is to use object spread operator.

As an example,

suppose you have a variable that you want to modify then do something with

```
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
const obj2 = testObj
obj2.a: 3


// result: obj1 = obj2 = {a:3, b:2}
```

The original object will be modified.  This is because the obj2 variable is essentially just a pointer to obj1 object.

Now suppose we use the spread operator instead

```
const obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
const obj2 = {...testObj}
obj2.a: 3

// result: obj1 = {a:1, b:2}, obj2 = {a:3, b:2}
```

The result of this will be that obj2 is properly updated but obj1 remains untouched.  The spread operator effectively create a shallow clone of obj1.  I have found the spread operator to be be particularly useful in modifying state in redux reducers.  If you set variables equal to state directly and make modify them, it will cause the problem you were experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use spreading, you can do this instead. Just change your `UpdateModel` function to

```
UpdateModel(){
  React.renderComponent(
    <Grid boxes={ _.clone(_.pull(model, _.sample(model))) } />, document.body
  );
}
```

Otherwise, the nextProp.boxes object with be the same object as the this.props.boxes object, so any alterations you made to it will be reflected in both.